# Why is this calling only the first method?

Tags: c#, methods, constructor

Im calling all the methods individually, but somehow only the first method is called and printed to the console, the charisma method in this case.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a desired target level");

    attributeConstructor("Charisma"); // We call the attribute Constructor evertime for a new variable
    attributeConstructor("Strength");
    attributeConstructor("Perception");
    attributeConstructor("Intelligence");
    attributeConstructor("Movement");
    attributeConstructor("Finesse");
    attributeConstructor("Willpower");
    attributeConstructor("Constitution");
}
```

This is what the `attributeConstructor` looks like, `attribute.name` is self explanatory, `attribute.level` and `attribute.modifier` are just some arithmetics.

```
// The aptly named attributeConstructor calls the attribute class to construct an attribute. No way!
static void attributeConstructor(string attributeName)
{
    Attribute attributePrintName = new Attribute(attributeName);
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Attribute: "
            + attributePrintName.name
            + " Level: "
            + attributePrintName.level
            + " Modifier: "
            + attributePrintName.modifier
    );
}
```

Let me know if I should post the full code. Stackoverflow doesn't want me to post "mostly code" in a question :/

Comment: You need to post code which reproduces the issue. This does not - [see it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nSwoyx)

Comment: Is `Attribute` in your code `System.Attribute`?

Comment: @GuruStron Sorry, I wanted to post the entire code but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me, heres the code https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEuARQ

I realise that when I enter more Values it also executes the other methods. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your `Attribute` class

```
public class Attribute
{
    int globalLevel = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // the rest is irrelevant
}
```

Oh hey, a field initializer for a non static field. Did you know that's going to run before your constructor every time you create a new instance? That means every time you write `new Attribute`, execution will stop on that `ReadLine()`. That's a bit awkward user experience, to be honest. You could make it `static`, but then it'd run before the first time you either instantiate the class or access any of its static members. That's even more awkward because it's even less obvious from any user of the class, and also that would make it a global variable, which is **bad**.

In general, I'm not a fan of side effects in constructors. Constructors should construct objects. If they need external data, it should be given to them.

It'd be better (and clearer) if instead of declaring it as a field, you instead added a parameter to your constructor. Then you read it only once (ideally just after that `"Please enter a desired target level"` prompt, which is probably what you were aiming for) and pass it in.

```
public class Attribute
{
    // no globalLevel field here!
    
    // other stuff
    
    public Attribute(string attributeName, int globalLevel)
    {
        // rest of constructor goes here
    }
}

static void attributeConstructor(string attributeName, int globalLevel)
{
    Attribute attributePrintName = new Attribute(attributeName, globalLevel);
    // snip
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a desired target level");
    int globalLevel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // so obvious, reading after writing that we want a value
    
    attributeConstructor("Charisma", globalLevel);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid writing "globalLevel" into every single constructor but I guess I don't really have a choice?

Comment: You could always make it `static` and assign it in `Main()`, but shared mutable state is always a bad idea in any design.